# How to retrieve all the group names of a particular folder in the Advanced permission tab

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript, sharepoint-permissions

I have a folder in document library and each folder in it has unique permissions.

[image]

Now I need to retrieve the permission group names attached to it using **javascript** only.
On click of advanced as given below

[image]

We get the groups and users who have permission to the folder.

[image]

I need only the SharePoint group names as the output using Javascript.

Can you please help me with this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I think you should first [get all unique permission for a folder](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/get-sharepoint-folder-permissions-javascript/) using `get_roleAssignments()`, then check if the retrieved permission type `get_principalType()` only equals to *SharePoint Group*.

> Download the JS script from **[GitHub](https://github.com/melqassas/JSforSharePoint)** and check the details at [How to Get SharePoint Folder Permissions Using JavaScript filtered by Groups or Users?](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/get-sharepoint-folder-permissions-javascript/)

Comment: Hi, Can you please help me with this.
My code isn't working with the follwing line. 
var GetRoles = curruntFolder.get_roleAssignments().getEnumerator();

Till role assignments its working. Then getEnumenrator() the code is stuck there.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery Ajax with REST API to achieve it.

**The following code for your reference:**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {      
    getFoldersRoleAssignments("Documents"); //Enter your Library name
});
    
function getFoldersRoleAssignments(listName){

    var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('"+listName+"')/folders?$expand=ListItemAllFields/RoleAssignments/Member";

    $.ajax({
        url: requestUri,
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
         headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"},
        success: function (data) {
            var html="";
            var folders=data.d.results;
            for(var i=0;i<folders.length;i++){          
                if(folders[i].ListItemAllFields.RoleAssignments!=null){
                    html+="<b><p>Folder Name: "+folders[i].Name+"</p></b>";
                    var roleAssignments=folders[i].ListItemAllFields.RoleAssignments.results;
                    for(var j=0;j<roleAssignments.length;j++){
                        html+="<p>"+roleAssignments[j].Member.Title+"</p>";
                    }
                }               
            }
            $("#foldersPermissions").html(html);
        },
        error: function (e) {
            //alert("Failed to get details");                
        }
    });
}
</script>
<div id="foldersPermissions"></div>
```

[image]

Comment: $("#foldersPermissions").html(html);
In this statement where do you declare  $("#foldersPermissions")